# How to bring the application to the front?

Tags: vb6

Currently copied and modifying a portion of a coding within the same program to create a button that when clicked will bring the Vision application to the front of the GUI.

- Created a button called "btVisionCam_Click()"
- Declared "Private lVideo As Long"
- CEIVidCap is the Vision application that is running behind of the GUI when the GUI is opened

```vb
Private Sub btVisionCam_Click()

    If btVisionCam.Value = 1 Then
        lVideo = FindWindow(vbNullString, "CEIVidCap")
            If lVideo = 0 Then
                lVideo = Shell("C:\machine\appls\CEIVidCap.exe", vbNormalFocus)
            End If
    End If

End Sub
```

When the button is clicked, it does not bring the Vision application to the front of the GUI. Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a module and copy the following declarations:

```
Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal nCmdShow As Long) As Long
```

Then in your button, as you are already doing, use `FindWindow` to get the window handle and use `ShowWindow` to bring it up:

```
Dim lnghWnd As Long

lnghWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, "CEIVidCap")
ShowWindow lnghWnd, 1
```

---

Supported values for `nCmdShow` parameter of `ShowWindow`:

```
SW_HIDE = 0
Hide the window.
SW_MAXIMIZE = 3
Maximize the window.
SW_MINIMIZE = 6
Minimize the window.
SW_RESTORE = 9
Restore the window (not maximized nor minimized).
SW_SHOW = 5
Show the window.
SW_SHOWMAXIMIZED = 3
Show the window maximized.
SW_SHOWMINIMIZED = 2
Show the window minimized.
SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE = 7
Show the window minimized but do not activate it.
SW_SHOWNA = 8
Show the window in its current state but do not activate it.
SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE = 4
Show the window in its most recent size and position but do not activate it.
SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
Show the window and activate it (as usual).
```

Comment: Please update your question with your current code so we can help troubleshoot

Comment: Hi Étienne Laneville, the codes still doesn't work.. When i clicked on the btVisionCam button the CEIVidCap window doesn't show up in front of the GUI. Another thing to point out is when the GUI is opened, the CEIVidCap window is already maximized and running behind of the GUI. Hope someone can help me to make it show up in the front of the GUI when the button is pressed..

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it as the foreground window.

Add this to your other API calls:

```
Declare Function Win32_SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
    Alias "SetForegroundWindow" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long) _
As Long
```

Then add:

```
Dim Ret As Long
Ret = Win32_SetForegroundWindow(lnghWnd)
If Ret Then
    ' Your window should be foreground
End If
```